# Woocommerce-the quantity and price next to the shopping cart pattern are not updated

Tags: bug

Use theme：https://envothemes.com/envo-ecommerce/
Situation: adding products in cart page, deleting products in cart page, using discount coupons, canceling discount coupons
Content:
After I click update on the shopping cart page, the quantity and price in the shopping cart icon are not updated.
Question: What code can I add in Function.php to solve this problem?(eg.jQuery)
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It has been solved, and if it has not been updated, use this jquery to update the div.

```
jQuery(".heading-row").load(location.href + " .heading-row");
```